# Why may classes be instantiated within static classes, such as main?

Tags: java, swing, static, program-entry-point, instantiation

I've been learning Java recently in my search for a programming language that isn't a nuisance to code GUI with (is it too much to ask for an easy way to make a window and add interface elements?), and I'm somewhat curious as to how dynamic and static programming intermingle in Java. Java asks me to declare my main class/entry point as:

```
public static void main(String[] args)...
```

Within main, I may declare instances with the following:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

Why is that, as opposed to `frame = new JFrame();` perfectly valid in Java?

Inn particular, when I mentally 'parse' the first, I read it as, "frame, an instance of JFrame, is a new instance of JFrame". To me, that seems somewhat redundant. The latter, which I read as, "frame is a new instance of JFrame" seems much more reasonable.

Moving on, I often, near the top of the class, define the variables that it will frequently use, especially constants or persistent display objects, so when I make a simple class, I usually declare something like `public JFrame frame`.

Is the redundancy in the proper instantiation, `JFrame frame = new JFrame()` the reason that I can delete these declarations with no apparent problem?

```
    public class Display {
        //The line below can be deleted with no apparent difference
        public JFrame frame; 

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Why do I need to declare the type of a variable I have 
         * already declared above? */
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        }
     }
```

In the case that I delete that declaration up top, am I right in assuming that frame becomes a child of the main method? In that case, declaring it up top makes it a child to Display?

Overall, I would like an explanation of instantiation through a static class. I really hope that I'm not asking a silly question, but I have found that online 'tutorials' usually take the form of a walkthrough that describes what the code does, but not why it is used that way; basically, I can't find the answer elsewhere and I know you guys have a lot of knowledge. I would really appreciate a thoughtful response, and if possible, the explanation of how to interact with the declared 'frame' in each of my examples.

I would also be quite happy for an explanation of why frame = new JFrame is invalid, even if I declare `public JFrame frame` up top.

Thank you very much for reading this and taking the time to respond ^_^

Comment: `JFrame frame = new JFrame;` *isn't* valid code. You'd need `JFrame frame = new JFrame();`

Comment: *Why do I need to declare the type of a variable I have already declared above?* - You don't, unless you want a **local** variable.

Comment: Oh, so I do. I properly typed it in on my project, but while typing from memory for the question, I forgot the brackets.

Comment: You might like to take read through [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have read through those articles before, but for the sake of being thorough, I read through it just now. It served as a reasonable refresher, but did not actually discuss what I was having trouble with. The closest that it came was in stating "class methods **cannot** access instance methods and variables directly".

Comment: *"is it too much to ask for an easy way to make a window and add interface elements?"*  A resizable GUI for multiple platforms and PLAFS?  IMO yes.  Unless you consider using layout managers to be easy.  (While they are not rocket science, they are also not easy.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a very significant difference between:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

and

```
frame = new JFrame();
```

The first version declares a new *local* variable (in the context you've given) and assigns it a value. That local variable is completely separate to the instance variable you declared within the `Display` class.

The latter snippet assigns a new value to an *existing* variable - except in this case it won't work because you have an *instance* variable but no instance of `Display`.

If you declare your `frame` variable as `static` rather than as an instance variable, you can assign to that within your `main` method:

```
public class Display {
    public static JFrame frame; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
 }
```

Or you could create a new instance of `Display` and assign a value to an instance variable within it:

```
public class Display {
    public JFrame frame; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        display.frame = new JFrame();
        display.frame.setSize(800, 600);
        display.frame.setVisible(true);
    }
 }
```

However:

- There's no indication that you're going to use the instance/static variable within `Display` anyway
- I'd *strongly* encourage you to always make your fields private

Comment: Thank you very much! You described exactly what I was misunderstanding and gave an example of how to rectify the problem so that I would be using my declaration above. As you correctly assumed, in this case, I will not being using separate instances of display. As for making them private, I tend to make my variables private, but for the sake of the example, it seemed reasonable to make it public. I'll keep your advice in mind while I work, because I can't see many places where public is necessary.

Comment: By the way, I did a bit more coding and thanks to your advice, I easily set up my display class so that I can bring up a new window with two lines of code, one running the constructor `Display(int width, int height, String title)` and one that sets the window visible. You saved me more than a couple of frustrating projects of coding each window with 20 lines of code, instead of focusing on the content.

Answer (score 1):

```
//The line below can be deleted with no apparent difference
public JFrame frame;
```

Yes, because it is an unused variable.

You are never using the instance field `frame` in your code.

Instead you have

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Why do I need to declare the type of a variable I have 
     * already declared above? */
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

which declares *a new, completely unrelated* local variable of the same name and type.